# sFTP using commercial certificate

Tags: ssh, sftp, ssl-certificate

Currently we have a sFTP but the certificate is only self sign. We are required now to use a valid commercial certificate.

Please help me to enlightened what type of certificate need to purchase and basically how it works to validate the certificate?

Protocol using: SSH2 based SFTP only on port 22

Answer (score 11, accepted):

None.

As you said, **SFTP is SSH2-based. It is not the same as FTPS (FTP over TLS) and does not use X.509 certificates in any way.** The server authentication in SSH2 is mostly based around "trust on *first* use", so the keys are not signed at all. However, many of the problems with self-signed certificates don't apply.

The only thing even remotely close is OpenSSH certificates, which aren't sold commercially – they were explicitly made for internal use, with each site creating its own CA. Also, only OpenSSH supports them, other SFTP clients only use basic keys or Kerberos.

---

That said, **if you *were* using FTPS**, it would work exactly the same way as TLS in web browsers (HTTPS) – it would use the same "TLS Server" certificate type, and the exact same validation methods (a preloaded list of "root authorities").

The only difference is that EV is usually *not* supported outside web browsers, so a regular organization- or domain-validated certificate would be fine.

---

Finally, there are some exceptions. (Just as some programmers can write Fortran in any language, some sysadmins manage to put X.509 everywhere.)

- The US government like to use their CAC cards for everything, and have patched X.509 PKI support even into SSH. But if that were your situation, I think you would've been *given* the correct certificate already, instead of having to ask on SuperUser.
- Similarly, various distributed research computing *grids* also have a SSH patch (GSI-SSH) which uses X.509 PKI. They use a root authority list separate from the main OS / web browser list; it has some commercial CAs and some run by grids themselves. They also use certificates slightly different from regular "TLS server" ones – called *"Grid server"* in commercial CAs.

That said, I don't think any of the exceptions apply here. Most likely, whoever wrote your requirements simply doesn't know SFTP from FTPS.

Comment: It's quite a stretch, but MAYBE someone wants to sign the *files* being downloaded, especially if they are code for Windows or Java; those use X.509 usually under public CAs (but internal CAs are possible).

Comment: Well yes, but that's a _slightly_ different question.